# Devops build pipeline not copying test files to bin folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a yaml file for my build pipeline in which I trigger my unit test project. This project has a few `.csv` and `.xls(x)` files included used for unit testing. Theses files are set to `Copy Always`.

All tests run fine on local machine. But when my tests are run in Devops then it seems like the files aren't copied over to the bin directory.

In my yaml I have this to run the test project:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test .NET core Application
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '$(testProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfig)'
```

In the build output log I see that the files are present on this location:

```
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\MyAppImport\Tests\Data\sales_04.csv (file)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\MyAppImport\Tests\Data\Sales_02.csv (file)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\MyAppImport\Tests\Data\sales_01.xls (file)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\MyAppImport\Tests\Data\sales_stock_01.csv (file)
```

But the actual test looks for the files in the `bin` folder:

```
Failed Throws_A_FileNotFound_When_The_File_Does_Not_Exist [1 ms]
  Error Message:
   Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<The file could not be found, read or did not contain data>. 

Actual:<The file 'D:\a\1\s\MyAppImport\Tests\bin\Release\net5.0\Data\sales_01.xls' could not be found, read or did not contain data>.
```

As you can see, the files paths are different. For some reason the files aren't copied to the `bin` folder, eventhough "Copy Always" is set for each file as build action.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: check the build step logs

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk What are you missing? There is no specific build step for running unit tests. The command it executes (according to my build log) is `"dotnet.exe" test D:\a\1\s\MyAppImport\Tests\Tests.csproj --logger trx --results-directory D:\a\_temp --configuration Release`